# Is Silverlight the right tool for a client application that resides as a webpage?

Tags: silverlight

I have to write an app that is available to everyone, that is, no single exe that you have to distribute but rather a webpage that will be used for doing mostly client side stuff, reading files writing to files and doing some stuff remotely on other machines.

I don't want to use javascript. Is Silverlight the best tool to use for this? I'm just not clear on the best uses of Silverlight.

OR

Would WPF/WCF be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with Silverlight Out of browser Application.[OOB](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/out-of-browser-applications/advanced-silverlight-out-of-browser-introduction)